# Updating Parameter Value in Java

Tags: java

I wasn't too sure what to title this so I apologize in advance. I am currently trying to make a game where the total points must add up to 100 for a player to win. I am running into the issue where the "PlayerTotalPoints" is not updating after the PlayerTurn method returns the amount of PlayerTotalPoints and sets that as the new value in PlayerTotalPoints to be rerun in the method once again.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int PlayerTotalPoints = 0;
        int ComputerTotalPoints = 0;
        while (!IsGameOver(PlayerTotalPoints, ComputerTotalPoints)) {
            int TurnPointCounter = 0;
            System.out.println("It is the player's turn!");
            PlayerTotalPoints = PlayerTurn(TurnPointCounter, PlayerTotalPoints);
            System.out.println("The player currently has " + PlayerTotalPoints + " total points!");
            System.out.println("It is the computer's turn!");
            ComputerTotalPoints = ComputerTurn(TurnPointCounter, ComputerTotalPoints);
            System.out.println("The computer currently has " + ComputerTotalPoints + " total points!");
        }
    }
```

The method PlayerTurn returns the new value of the PlayerTotalPoints (I checked and it is returning the correct value of PlayerTotalPoints) but for some reason this value is not carrying over to the PlayerTotalPoints variable which needs to keep going as a player accumulates their score. This is for an assignment so I am not sure how much of my code I am allowed to share online but if you need more examples of my code just let me know, thanks.

EDIT: These are the PlayerTurn and ComputerTurn methods:

```
    public static int PlayerTurn(int counter, int PlayerTotalPoints) {
        System.out.println("The player currently has " + counter + " turn points.");
        System.out.println("Do you want to play or hold this turn? (P/H)");
        String answer = scan.nextLine();
        answer = answer.replaceAll(" ", "");
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
        if (answer.equals("H")) {
            PlayerTotalPoints += counter;
            System.out.println("You have elected to hold this turn.");
//            System.out.println("You currently have " + PlayerTotalPoints + " total points.");
            System.out.println(PlayerTotalPoints);
            return PlayerTotalPoints;
        }
        int[] OneRoll = RollDice();
        int TurnCount = Turn(OneRoll, counter);
        if (OneRoll[0] == 6 && OneRoll[1] == 6) {
            PlayerTotalPoints = 0;
            return PlayerTotalPoints;
        }
        if (OneRoll[0] == 6 | OneRoll[1] == 6) {
//            System.out.println("The player currently has " + PlayerTotalPoints + " total points.");
            return PlayerTotalPoints;
        }
        PlayerTurn(TurnCount, PlayerTotalPoints);
        return PlayerTotalPoints;
    }

    public static int ComputerTurn(int counter, int ComputerTotalPoints) {
        System.out.println("The computer currently has " + counter + " turn points.");
        int n = generator.nextInt(100);
        if (n >= 70) {
            ComputerTotalPoints += counter;
            System.out.println("The computer has decided to hold this turn. ");
//            System.out.println("The computer currently has " + ComputerTotalPoints + " total points.");
            return ComputerTotalPoints;
        }
        int[] CompRoll = RollDice();
        int CompTurnCount = Turn(CompRoll, counter);
        if (CompRoll[0] == 6 && CompRoll[1] == 6) {
            ComputerTotalPoints = 0;
            return ComputerTotalPoints;
        }
        if (CompRoll[0] == 6 | CompRoll[1] == 6) {
//            System.out.println("The computer currently has " + ComputerTotalPoints + " total points.");
            return ComputerTotalPoints;
        }
        ComputerTurn(CompTurnCount, ComputerTotalPoints);
        return ComputerTotalPoints;
    }
```

Comment: Can't really comment anything because I can't see the whole code but would suggest you to take a look at java naming conventions.

Comment: Can you post the code for `IsGameOver`, `PlayerTurn` and `ComputerTotalPoints`?  Also, try and start using Java naming conventions - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: @mjuarez Yes, just posted those methods now. And thanks for the link I'll give it a look now

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I just posted the three other methods involved in this program, does this help?

Comment: It's hard to understand without seeing the full code. But I think you need to put your PlayerTotalPoints variable outside of the method.

Comment: @Samasha I just posted the full code now, and our instructor does not want us to use any variables outside of our methods (unless they are declared final)

Comment: Put you're TurnPointCounter variable declaration outside the while loop

Comment: @AmanDhaliwal  I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the following:

```
    PlayerTurn(TurnCount, PlayerTotalPoints);
    return PlayerTotalPoints;
```

be something like

```
    PlayerTotalPoints = PlayerTurn(TurnCount, PlayerTotalPoints);
    return PlayerTotalPoints;
```

For both PlayerTurn and ComputerTurn method calls?   Remember, this is a recursive call.

Comment: Yes the TurnPointCounter is getting set to zero at the end of each round so the points reset in between rounds. At the end of each round, the TurnPointCounter is added to the current players Total Points.

Comment: It's reset.  But where do you do something with it?.  You are redeclaring it inside the while loop.  It never changes.

Comment: The TurnPointCounter is being passed as a parameter into the PlayerTurn method and the ComputerTurn method so they both start their turns with 0 turn points.

Comment: Where do you update TurnPointCounter?  Where do you add something to it?  If your not using it, just pass a 0 to the method.  The way you are doing it is confusing with the limited code provided.

Comment: Yeh it is the exact same as passing a 0 into the method, it was just helpful for me to do that when I was writing the code.

Comment: Without seeing the other methods I can't really help much.

Comment: I just posted the full code now for the program now